# SSAS Conditional cube calculated member

Tags: conditional-statements, ssas, cube

I'm new to SSAS and cubes.

I have a simple database table:

```
product|value|status  
-------|-----|------  
A|100|1  
B|20|0  
A|20|0  
B|80|1
```

Status field denotes whether it is planned sale or already closed one.

I'd like to have measures in the cube for 
Planned (0) sale and Closed(1) sale. They should sum value per product in given status.

Output cube should look as follows:

```
product|planned sale|closed sale    
------|---------|-----------  
A|20|100  
B|20|80
```

I have measure for value and status. However, no matter how I slice the function, boolean in status is aggregated. I guess my measure is configured wrong. I tried setting it to boolean, however it appears to do "and" computation.

I tried IFF and .currentmember hoping it would iterate.

I must be missing something basic, please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a simple Status dimension, with 0 for Planned and 1 for Closed.

It's getting aggregated because right now you're using it as a measure.

EDIT based on your comment:

I believe you are incorrectly assuming that SSAS will interpret the value of measures.status as a Boolean.   SQL does not have a concept of a Boolean datatype.  Although the `bit` datatype can be used to hold Boolean values, in SQL you cannot say `IF [MyBitColumn] THEN ...`  Instead you have to say `IF [MyBitColumn]=1 THEN ...`.   SQL Server does NOT automatically understand/assume that 1 = true, and 0 = false.

Try this for your calculated measure:

```
 iif([Measures].[Status]=1, [Measures].[Value],0)  //closed sale
 iif([Measures].[Status]=0, [Measures].[Value],0)  //planned sale
```

Comment: While that works, to satisfy requirements i need to be able to create separate calculated measures rather then one controlled by dimension. I'm looking for a hint on how to configure calculated measure to do equivalent of "sumif" function in excel :)

Comment: Post your attempt to use IIF(), so we can debug it.

Comment: i tried:  iif([Measures].[Status], [Measures].[Value],0) for ones that evaluate to 1 and ![Meaures].[Status] for ones that do not. However, it seems to aggregate [Status] although the [Status] measure is set to no agggregates.

Comment: Thanks Tab, that unfortunatelly doesn't work :( Seems that SSAS does recognize the boolean values, it returns them as true/false to cube. Even sets it as a source datatype in cube for measure. In product that has both 1 and 0 status, it doesn't catch into either of iifs :(

Comment: trying with different datasets here is what i found out: true = -1 false = 0 :) While single rows of data will work properly with iif you posted ( assuming adjustment to -1 for true ), once aggregated, they will sum up everything if any true value is found. I'm having hard time believing that this is something way out of ordinary, however at this stage, i'll just add two columns to the DB and have them calculate automatically... thanks for trying to help Tab.